# Timetask always execute

Tags: java

i want to run my code every wednesday each week at midnight.

```
public class Autonom extends TimerTask {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    Calendar data = Calendar.getInstance();
    data.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.WEDNESDAY);
    data.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    data.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    data.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    data.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    timer.schedule(new Autonom(), data.getTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(1, TimeUnit.DAYS));

}

@Override
public void run() {
...
}

}
```

The problem is that when i start this code, the run method is execute each time. So whats the problem?

Comment: I guess you have also to set the month and year field because the docs says that the task is executeted if the point of time is in the past [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long)). If I run the code and print the `data.getTime()` i've got following output Wed Dec 28 00:00:00 CET 2016 and this date lies in the past

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the current time and set it to midnight on Wednesday. Since we are friday today, wednesday is in the past.

From the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long)), you can see what happen in that case

> if the scheduled first time is in the past, it is scheduled for immediate execution.

If you want to wait the next wednesday to start the execution, increment the week.

```
data.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
```

This will be a date in the futur and will wait until then to start the first execution.